# Getting to know which value corresponds to a particular column value

Tags: python, dataframe, categorical-data, label-encoding

I wish to find the exact value of the index for an input defined value of key in a dataframe, below is the code I am trying to do to get it.

data_who = pd.DataFrame({'index':data['index'],
'Publisher_Key':data['Key']})

Below is my O/P dataframe:

[image]

If suppose I give an input say 100 as the key value, I would like to get the O/P of the index value, which is Goat, what should I do in my code??

PS: Too many labels in the data after performing label encoding, so wanted to know the value of the labels corresponds to which category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `index` is a column, then you can do as follows:

```py
data.loc[data['Key'] == 100, 'index'].iloc[0]
>>> 'Zebra'
```

Or other option:

```py
data[data['Key'] == 100]['index'].iloc[0]
>>> 'Zebra'
```

If index is the index of the dataframe, replace `['index']` with `.index`.

As a side note: you shouldn't name a column `index` in pandas, it's a concept itself and naming a column that way could be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest three ways of doing this:

1. Using pandas:

```
data_who.loc[data_who['key'] == 100, 'index'].values[0]
>>> 'Goat'
```

2. Using python dictionaries:

```
who_dict = dict(zip(data_who['key'], data_who['index']))
who_dict[100]
>>> 'Goat'
```

3. Finally, if you were using `LabelEncoder` from skearn, it can inverse transform values:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(animals) # fit on the list of animals
le.inverse_transform([100])
```